# PrimeFaces Fileupload return "servlet Faces Servlet threw exception"

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, servlets, primefaces

I'm using PF 4.0, Glassfish 3, JSF and Hibernate. I'm try using primefaces fileupload to upload image to database. When I run my code and call method upload, I get this error:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at bean.imageUpload.handleFileUpload(imageUpload.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:290)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:740)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:943)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here is my fully code. Hope anyone suggest me. Thank you.

**xhtml**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imageUpload.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                  update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
</h:form>
```

**bean imageUpload (sessionscoped)**

```
public class imageUpload implements Serializable {

private Products seletedproduct;
private List<Products> product;

/** Creates a new instance of imageUpload */
public imageUpload() {
}

public Products getSeletedproduct() {
    return seletedproduct;
}

public void setSeletedproduct(Products seletedproduct) {
    this.seletedproduct = seletedproduct;
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    System.out.println(file.getFileName());

    byte[] img = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputstream());

    System.out.println(img);

    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        seletedproduct.setImage(img);
        session.beginTransaction().begin();
        session.save(seletedproduct);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("Saved Successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: which is the line 34 of your imageUpload.handleFileUpload ?

Comment: @HatemAlimam where is it bro?

Comment: You are having nullPointer at line 34, I'm trying to figure out which line is that in your IDE ...

Comment: @HatemAlimam I updated my code and new error, hope you check it.

Comment: All I can see that this problem is not related to primefaces upload.. some of your objects inside the handle method is not initialised ...

Comment: @HatemAlimam i think so but i can't figure out what is my problem?

Comment: You need to debug in this case, and see where the exception is thrown inside the method...

Comment: @HatemAlimam in debug mode, it show "seletedproduct.setImage(img)" is cause, but how can I fix it?

Comment: @balusc hope you give my some advices

Comment: update your post with the code of selecting the selectedproduct ...

Comment: @HatemAlimam what code line should I edit?

Comment: @thehung1724 somewhere in your xml you have a control that sets seletedproduct or maybe someone in the bean you set seletedproduct. Update your question with the xml or Java code that sets that variable.  What's happening is that seletedproduct is not set causing the null pointer error.